# Google Custom Search not return results of certain pages

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console, google-custom-search, web-crawler

There are some pages under the same directory doesn't show in Google Custom Search at all. These pages are linked by other pages as well.

And the strange part is that if I logged in the [Webmaster Tool], those links

- show in [Internal Links] section
- show "Complete" status if I test them in [Fetch as Google]
- passed the [robots.txt Tester] not showing
- in Crawl Errors

These pages are marked as "daily" in "Frequency" and "1" in "Priority" in sitemap.xml. These pages are the most important section on the website I am working on. But they doesn't show at all...

Does anyone knows how can i test and find out the root cause of this behavior?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

finally found out that our officer added a rule that will exclude everything. Initially we thought that rule is wrong and won't match anything, but we observed that Google Custom Search will add a trailing slash and thus the rule match.
Wish i never post this question